# Extract specific number from text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, grep

I have a text file test.hd with contents

```
gated window upper limit:=1.15
gated window lower limit:=0.87
gated frame mode:=variable time
gated beats accepted:=631
gated beats rejected:=1
gated longest beat:=1.0455
gated shortest beat:=0.8722
gated average beat:=0.9472
applied zoom:=2.15
zoom origin x:=272
zoom origin y:=288
```

In my shell script I would like to assign a variable longest beat and shortest beat using sed or a perl one liner. At the moment I could do it with more, grep and a cut

```
more test.hd | grep 'longest beat' | cut -f 2 -d =
```

Comment: You need to set environment variables, or to do something with these values in the script?

Comment: I wish to do something with these values in the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to capture the target values:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($short, $long);
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/longest beat:=(\S+)/) {
        $long = $1;
    } elsif (/shortest beat:=(\S+)/) {
        $short = $1;
    }
}
print "Longest beat: $long\n";
print "Shortest beat: $short\n";

__DATA__
gated window upper limit:=1.15
gated window lower limit:=0.87
gated frame mode:=variable time
gated beats accepted:=631
gated beats rejected:=1
gated longest beat:=1.0455
gated shortest beat:=0.8722
gated average beat:=0.9472
applied zoom:=2.15
zoom origin x:=272
zoom origin y:=288
```

**Output:**

```
Longest beat: 1.0455
Shortest beat: 0.8722
```

The `DATA` file handle can be any file handle you require, of course, this is just for demonstration.

A more generalized version is to simply extract all the key/value pairs:

```
my %data;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $value) = split /:=/, $_, 2;   # split on := max two fields
    $data{$key} = $value;
}
print "Longest beat: $data{'gated longest beat'}\n";
print "Shortest beat: $data{'gated shortest beat'}\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
longest_beat=$(sed -n '/longest beat/s/.*=//p' test.hd)
shortest_beat=$(sed -n '/shortest beat/s/.*=//p' test.hd)
```

Answer (score 1):

`more` is not needed here. You can specify the filename for `grep` or redirect it to its standard input. Then, use the Command Substitution:

```
longest_beat=$(grep 'longest beat' test.hd | cut -d= -f2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I do something similar in perl/sed? The reason I ask is the script is currently in csh and I was pondering whether to translate to perl ?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
my ($longest_beat, $shortest_beat);

while (<DATA>) { # insert your own filehandle here
  $longest_beat  = $1, next if /longest beat:=\s*(\S+)/; 
  $shortest_beat = $1, next if /shortest beat:=\s*(\S+)/;
}

print $longest_beat, "\n";
print $shortest_beat, "\n";
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/7bifKm).

Answer (score 1):

```
long=`perl -F"=" -ane 'print $F[1] if(/longest beat/)' your_file`
short=`perl -F"=" -ane 'print $F[1] if(/shortest beat/)' your_file`
```

also you can use:

```
sed -n 's/.*longest beat:=//gp'
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
gated window upper limit:=1.15
gated window lower limit:=0.87
gated frame mode:=variable time
gated beats accepted:=631
gated beats rejected:=1
gated longest beat:=1.0455
gated shortest beat:=0.8722
gated average beat:=0.9472
applied zoom:=2.15
zoom origin x:=272
zoom origin y:=288
> 
> 
> 
> cat temp.sh
#!/bin/sh


long=`perl -F"=" -ane 'print $F[1] if(/longest beat/)' temp`
short=`perl -F"=" -ane 'print $F[1] if(/shortest beat/)' temp`

echo $long
echo $short
> 
> 
> ./temp.sh
1.0455
0.8722
>
> cat temp.sh
#!/bin/sh


long=`sed -n 's/.*longest beat:=//gp' temp`
short=`perl -F"=" -ane 'print $F[1] if(/shortest beat/)' temp`

echo $long
echo $short
> ./temp.sh
1.0455
0.8722
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using captures with a hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
    $hash{$1} = $2 if /((?:longest|shortest) beat):=(\S+)/;
}

print "\u$_: $hash{$_}\n" for keys %hash;

__DATA__
gated window upper limit:=1.15
gated window lower limit:=0.87
gated frame mode:=variable time
gated beats accepted:=631
gated beats rejected:=1
gated longest beat:=1.0455
gated shortest beat:=0.8722
gated average beat:=0.9472
applied zoom:=2.15
zoom origin x:=272
zoom origin y:=288
```

Output:

```
Shortest beat: 0.8722
Longest beat: 1.0455
```